# What does {% url %} mean in django?

Tags: django, pinax

```
<a href={% url home %}></a>
```

I can't find {% url %}  in the Django API.

Comment: You can't have been looking very hard, since it's clearly documented in the list of built-in template tags.

Comment: Maybe it's not in the *Chinese Language* documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[url](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

> Returns an absolute URL (i.e., a URL
>   without the domain name) matching a
>   given view function and optional
>   parameters. This is a way to output
>   links without violating the DRY
>   principle by having to hard-code URLs
>   in your templates:

```
{% url path.to.some_view arg1,arg2,name1=value1 %}
```

Comment: Nice, I *really* ought to use this. I hard code far too many urls in my templates!